Why do I get a NullReferenceException when using () but not without () in Func<T>?
I am using a Func in my WPF application, and before initializing it, I tried to assign it to another variable. Here’s what I encountered:
Code:
Func<string> GetFunc;
Case 1:
var func = GetFunc();
This results in a NullReferenceException, indicating that GetFunc was null.
Case 2:
var func = GetFunc;
In this case, no exception is thrown, and func is simply assigned the value null.
Can anyone explain why I get a NullReferenceException when using () but not when assigning the delegate directly without ()?

An assignment of null is totally legal and will not cause an exception ( => the case without '()'). var func = GetFunc();, however, attempts to execute the delegate and assign its return value, but the delegate is null. And that will cause a NullReferenceException. If you do var func = GetFunc; and go on to do var result = func();, then that will also throw.

The difference here is that var func = GetFunc(); will try to call GetFunc() and if GetFunc is null, you'll get the NullReferenceException. However var func = GetFunc; will just assign the value of GetFunc to func without trying to call it - thus func will just be assigned the value null. (GetFunc is a delegate type.)

Sometimes it helps to avoid var

Imagine we had a similar situation that didn't involve delegates, or even fields - just local variables so it's really clear that the value is a null reference:
string x = null;

// Case 1:
var y = x; // No exception

// Case 2:
var y = x.ToUpperInvariant(); // Exception

Hopefully that's entirely familiar, and the cause of the exception is obvious.
Now let's bring delegates back in, but remove the C# shorthand for invocation:
Func<bool> x = null;

// Case 1:
var y = x; // No exception

// Case 2:
var y = x.Invoke(); // Exception

All I've done is change the type of x and change the method being invoked from ToUpperInvariant to Invoke.
Now, x() is just a shorthand C# provides for x.Invoke() - so they should behave the same way.
At this point, it should feel entirely natural that copying the delegate reference to another variable doesn't throw an exception even if that reference is null, but invoking the delegate does throw an exception.
